# Angular - Pass component name as parameter in http interceptor automatically

Tags: angular

In angular app, I make API calls using http service with interceptor that add headers to the request.
I'm looking for a way to pass the calling component name as http header, without having to add it as a parameter every time I call the http service.
For example, from MyComponent:

```js
this.HttpService.GetSomethingName("MyComponent",SomethingID); // annoying
```

whould be very annoying
so if I could call the service like :

```js
this.HttpService.GetSomethingName(SomethingID); // simple
```

and then in the service somehow get the component name it would be cleaner and simpler

any ideas?

Comment: It is difficult to achieve this, even though if you can able to extract the component name using `this.contstructor.name`(of component), when code is minified the class name may change form `AppComponent` to `A`. Also you can not directly grad component name inside `service`

Comment: I can use a property to store the name of the component or give it a unique key for the minifying problem. But still I have to pass that key every call to the service. That key has nothing to do with the the service logic but I must pass it to the server for logging and security issues.

Comment: I've tried to solve the problem, but you can not really get read of the parameter, but certainly you can do something like this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fj2knm 
can you please try this and let me know if it works?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you call `GetSometingName()` a lot of times in `MyComponent`, then why not just create a method in `MyComponent` that does that:

```js
private GetSomethingName(id: SomeIdType): void {
    this.HttpService.GetSomethingName("MyComponent", SomethingID);
}
```

But if you're looking to call various methods and prepending the arguments for each one, then I cannot think of anything.